# Export Matplotlib contour plot as geojson polygons

Tags: javascript, python, json, d3.js, geojson

A little background on the data I'm using. I'm plotting 2m temperature contours from the NCEP NOMADS data server (in particular from the 00p25 degree GFS).

I've discovered the geojsoncontour python3 module, which works really well, however it creates a geojson file with a collection of LineFeatures. I'm interested in shading the areas between the contours...so it seems as though I would need a collection of Polygons to accomplish this...which geojsoncontour does not support.

I've tried using the geojson python package to create a geojson file from the vertex data in the matplotlib contour plot...but this is proving to be more difficult than I thought. Eg. there are some areas where there is a minima in the data...and several polygons are on top of one another([see attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll0iD.png)). I have no idea how to check to see if there is a polygon in a polygon, so that I can create a polygon with a "hole" in it from the other polygon so that the data could be appropriately styled.

Like I said, this is proving to be rather complicated. Does anyone have any recommendations on how to create a collection of polygon features from the matplotlib contour data? Maybe there is a different way to go about creating shading from my datafile which can be done directly in the browswer...maybe using a canvas (Which I also wasn't able to find much help with).

Thanks!

```
    #Code attempting to create polygons from contour data
    #Code is only complete for the case where there are minima in the data 
    #(eg. where the contour is closed)
    def contour_to_geojson(contour, geojson_filepath, contour_levels):
        collections = contour.collections
        contour_index = 0
        assert len(contour_levels) == len(collections)
        poly_features = []
        for collection in collections:
            paths = collection.get_paths()
            for path in paths:
                vert = path.vertices
                #Check to see if the path is already closed
                #There are issues with comparing floats, so set up a cutoff
                #threshold instead of directly comparing values
                bounds_lon = abs(vert[0][0]-vert[len(vert)-1][0])
                bounds_lat = abs(vert[0][1]-vert[len(vert)-1][1])
                #print(bounds_lon)
                #0.000001 is essentially 0
                coordinates = []
                if bounds_lon < 0.00001 and bounds_lat < 0.00001:
                    compliant_vert = []
                    for v in vert:
                        lat = np.asscalar(vert[v][1])
                        lon = np.asscalar(vert[v][0])
                        compliant_vert.append((lon, lat))
                    coordinates.append(compliant_vert)
                else:
                    #Still need to write code for this section
                    #Will create polygon coords using contours on either side as bounds
                if contour_index < len(contour.collections):
                    poly = Polygon(coordinates)
                    properties = {
                    "title": "%.2f" % contour_levels[contour_index]
                    }
                    poly_features.append(Feature(geometry=poly,    properties=properties))
         contour_index += 1

    feature_collection = FeatureCollection(poly_features)
    dump = geojson.dumps(feature_collection, sort_keys=True)
    with open(geojson_filepath, 'w') as fileout:
        fileout.write(dump)
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Check my edited question, I'm more looking for an answer with psuedo code, but I've included my code in case that helps